# Is the following use of "imperative" good style?

Tags: writing-style

I wrote the following as part of an article in the making:

> Diverse fields such as medicine, sociology, and marketing require the collection, analysis, and publication of large amounts of personal data. At some stage during this process it becomes imperative, for the protection of individual privacy, that such data be sanitized to remove information that could potentially identify some set of personal data as belonging to a certain individual.

Is "becomes imperative ... that such data be sanitized" good style? Is the above OK, in general?

Comment: I responded at first to suggest an alternative, but I read your sentence too hastily. Yours is fine as it stands. If you already read my answer, please disregard it.

Comment: @Robusto: You should make that an actual answer so it can be up-voted. :)

Comment: @Shaun: OK, done. :) My main concern was that I didn't want him to puzzle over my unnecessary correction.

Answer (score 5):

I responded at first to suggest an alternative, but I read your sentence too hastily. Yours is fine as it stands. If you already read my other answer, please disregard it.

Comment: Thank you. I did read your first answer once, but I have forgotten what it was, so no harm done :) .

Answer (score 3):

*Imperative* is an adjective that means *of vital importance, crucial*; the sentence containing *imperative* can be written as

> At some stage during this process it becomes crucial, for the protection of individual privacy, that such data be sanitized to remove information that could potentially identify some set of personal data as belonging to a certain individual.

To reply to your question, it is good style.

Answer (score 0):

*Imperative* implies an imperator, which is contradicted by the passive construction of *data be sanitized*.  Perhaps you should substitute *privacy laws and ethics require the researcher to sanitize […]*.

Comment: Didn't downvote, but I disagree. His use is consistent with my personal conversational experience. That said, do you have a citation for the necessity of an imperator? I'm interested to see if my experience thus far includes incorrect uses.

Comment: @Malvolio : I didn't downvote either, and would be interested in a reference just like @Andy. Thank you.

Comment: @Andy: _"imperative" implies an imperator_ is false; _imperative_ means _of vital importance_ or _crucial_, but it doesn't mean _of vital importance for an imperator_. If you are looking for the adjective that means _of the imperator_ or _of an imperator_, then you are looking for _imperatorial_. In most of the cases, you would use _imperator_, as in _this is the imperator's sword_.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: That's basically what I thought, which is why I was wondering if he had a citation. Thanks for helping clear it up.

Comment: @Andy: The definition I used in my answer is taken from the _New Oxford American Dictionary_. I am sure other dictionaries report a similar definition of _imperative_. As a side note, _imperative_ has an equivalent in Italian (_imperativo_), which is also used in phrases like _imperativo categorico_.

Comment: @Malvolio: You cannot down vote your own answers. **:-)**

Comment: Wow, you people are literal-minded.  I supposed on an English-grammar blog, I shouldn't be surprised.  Let me rephrase.  "When you say 'imperative', you are using a muscular and authoritative tone but then you switch to the aptly named passive voice."